# Откуда в объекта свойство picture_set из примера документации Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

Взял пример с [документации](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-2.1.x/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html) по джанго CMS.

Вот модель:

```
    class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'gallery'

class Picture(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/images/")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

Регистрация плагина:

```
    @plugin_pool.register_plugin
class CMSGalleryPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = GalleryPlugin
    name = _("Gallery")
    render_template = "gallery/gallery.html"
    module = "Mgroup blocks"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({
            'gallery':instance.gallery,
            'instance':instance,
            'placeholder':placeholder
        })
        return context
```

И самая не понятная часть для меня, это темплейт:

```
{% for image in gallery.picture_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.description }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

На сколько я понимаю - мы передаем в контекст галерею и проходимся по каждой картинке, привязанной к галерее, выводим её. Я не нашел откуда взялся picture_set. Пытался сделать подобный фокус с другими моделями, но никаких сетов там нету, и привязка делается через фильтры, например по первичному ключу:

```
    subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(pk=given_pk)
subcategory.category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть одна "основная" модель `Gallery`, с которой может быть связано множество объектов `Picture`. Связь - `ForeignKey` идёт через поле `picture`.

В функции `render` вы определили один объект `Gallery` - `gallery`. Как я понял, теперь вы хотите получите все связанные объекты `Picture` к этому объекту.

Согласно `django api`, для того, чтобы получить все связанные элементы, есть 2 способа, насколько я знаю:

1. обращаться через `_set.all` (перед этим написав название связанной модели в стиле `lowercase`).
2. добавить в поле, через которое происходит связь, аргумент `related_name`. Например,

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pictures')
```

Тогда можно будет обращаться так:

```
{% for picture in gallery.pictures %}
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

В официальной [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/) написано что при создании подобного рода моделей автоматически генерируются свойства для доступа к зависимым моделям. Например если у нас есть зависимость один ко многим

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

То мы свободно можем обращаться к автогенерируемому свойству объекта Reporter  с использованием синтаксиса `reporter.article_set.` где мы к вложенным моделям обращаемся путем дописывания к их названию `_set` что является довольно таки удбным решением.

Если мы спользуем `ManyToMany` зависимость то мы можем обращаться к записям в бд с помощью `_set` и дописыванием название контейнера в множеством числе. Например:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

Чтобы обратится к вложенным моделям используем свойство `topping.pizza_set` а если к объектам-контейнерам то `pizza.toppings.`